# How do I safely discharge this Trinitron CRT when the HV connector seems glued on?

Tags: discharge, crt

I'm trying to discharge a Sony PVM-1353MD which suffered shipping damage. Unfortunately, I am unable to get my tool under the HV connector. It seems bonded to the CRT with some kind of white silicone like material. I tried to pry under both the black and white parts of the cap and can't get under it without damaging it. Most HVs are easy to discharge.

[image: HV Connector]

EDIT:

Found this label affixed to the inside cabinet:

[image: Warning label]

Comment: What will you be doing, that it needs to be discharged?  If you can't get at it, maybe it doesn't matter.  If there might be H.V. on "something else", then ground all the "something else".  Does the H.V. lead unplug at the other end?

Comment: I believe so. see the red wires plug into a red canister.

Comment: I need to remove the crt from the frame and store it.

Comment: Source end cap may come off. | Leave it a few days and safety near certain. | Desperate mode: Make a small hole in  the EHT lead with a fine pin or similar. Having it on the end of a suitable insulator is advised :-). Make hole at optimum location for later repair with "stuff".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon♦ no, don't perforate any wire insulation ... slide a sewing needle under the rubber cap where the lead attaches to the tube ... it should push through the white silicone seal easily

Comment: I have a non-contact voltage meter. Would it help determine wether the tube is completely discharged?  I have the service manual for this model and it doesn't specify a procedure for discharging the CRT.  It does, however, instruct you how to remove the HV connector, but only if you need to remove the CRT. The procedure is to peel off the anode cap using your bare fingers and then pinch and pull. Pretty terrifying!  Perhaps, Sony profits life insurance policies on their technicians.

Comment: @jsotola  That would work but the surface around it is coated in conductive [aquadag](https://wiki2.org/en/Aquadag). IF he wanted to reseal the connector a defect at the edge may lead to early breakdown. Or not :-). | Puncturing the wire insulation is certainly not the best idea going - but I'd be fairly confident of being able to rebuild the insulation in some manner. My confidence may prove to be misplaced :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The manual briefly describes it as RTV and warns against removing it unless you're replacing the CRT.